# Spring boot: How to Save data to specific DTYPE

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

**I have this entity:**

```
public class StatementLinesEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long statementLinesId;
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateOperation;
private String operationNature;
private BigDecimal amount;
private String debitAmount;
```

**And this entity has Inheritance of type SINGLE_TABLE:**

```
  @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
  public class OperationCreditEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long operationCreditId;
  @CreatedDate
  private Date operationDate;
  @OneToOne
  private StatementLinesEntity statementLine;
```

**And these 3 enteties inherite of it :**

```
  @Entity
  @DiscriminatorValue("Espece")
  public class OperationEspecesEntity extends OperationCreditEntity {
  private String cin;
  private String nomEmetteur;
  private String prenomEmetteur;
  =============================
  @DiscriminatorValue("Virement")
  public class OperationVirementEntity extends OperationCreditEntity {
  private String rib;
  ===========================
  @Entity
  @DiscriminatorValue("Cheque")
  public class OperationChequeEntity extends OperationCreditEntity{
  private int numeroCheque;
```

Let's suppose I have a `List<StatementLinesEntity>` consist of 2 lines, on line has `debitAmount = C` and `operationNature = Virement` and second line has `debitAmount = C` and `operationNature = Espece`. My goal is to persist each line in a specific `DTYPE`. example
first line should be persisted in `OperationCreditEntity table DTYPE = Virement` and the second should be persisted in `OperationCreditEntity table DTYPE = Espece`

Comment: I don't follow the question - you mention DB rows, but you have java classes and entities. Are you not creating OperationEspecesEntity, OperationVirementEntity, and OperationChequeEntity instances for your data? Why would you duplicate the columns from StatementLinesEntity into a separate OperationCreditEntity table (assuming dateOperation~operationDate, DTYPE~operationNature). One should just reference the other (DB normalization) - StatementLinesEntity should have a reference to OperationCreditEntity instead of holding the operationNature directly.

Comment: Yes, why I'm not creating instances it's because I'm creeating a service which will be responsible just for this operations all transactions will be migrated to `OperationCreditEntity` table this process will be done automatically it's like you give 100000 lines and this services will put each line to the specific DTYPE based on these 2 conditions: must have `C` in `debitAmount`  and may have one of these 3 words: `Virement or Espece or Cheque` in `operationNature`.

Comment: As I said this is a service responsible for this proccess, the thing that i didn't found a way of the logic how to reach that goal. Really I'm stuck on this point about 2 days no solutions. If you know something please tell

Comment: Still not clear - what do you have now specifically? Is this a migration of existing StatementLinesEntity table data into another table format, or are you taking in user data and wondering how to turn your existing StatementLinesEntity data into this quasi OperationCreditEntity java data objects; A for loop taking your StatementLinesEntity instance to create a OperationCreditEntity  instance from it with spring repo.save() call on the result

Comment: If you have control of the incoming data itself, (ie JSON) you can just have it built directly into a StatementLinesEntity that references a OperationCreditEntity, the parsers can build it for you with small changes I hinted at so that you don't need to duplicate the dateOperation and operationNature data into both entities/tables

Comment: Okay, consider this scenario I have a `StatementLinesEntity` table on mysql with 100000 records npw my table will have all fields with data (id,date, bigDecimal amount, C, Virement) where `C` refers to `debitAmount` and `Virement` refers to `operationNature`, in my database i have another 4 tables `OperationCreditEntity` annotated with @Inheritance of type SINGLE_TABLE and the 3 other tables inherit from it(OperationVirementEntity,OperationChequeEntity,OperationEspeceEntity), till now everything is clear.

Comment: Now on my service I'll go to database and loop over all `StatementLinesEntity` lines and then filter every line that has `debitAmount == C` and `operationNature == Virement or Cheque or Espece` (it could be other data which hasn't these conditions I'll ignore them) after filter and returning a new List(a list which has all `debitAmount == C`, I want to persist every record to `OperationCreditEntity` into a specific DTYPE based on `operationNature` for example: first record of the list has `debitAmount == C` and `operationNature == Virement` my service persist this line as `DTYPE = Virement`

Comment: in the table `OperationCreditEntity`. now the second record has `debitAmount == C` and `operationNature == Cheque` the service should persist this line as `DTYPE = Cheque` in the table `OperationCreditEntity`. third record has  `debitAmount == C` and `operationNature == Espece`  he service should persist this line as `DTYPE = Espece` and so on ...and everyline saved in `OperationCreditEntity` table will have a FK of `StatementLinesEntity` because I have @OneToOne with `StatementLinesEntity` in  `OperationCreditEntity`. I dont know if you get the idea.

Comment: You mix 'entity' or java data class with table. My understanding of everything was you only have 2 tables. One for StatementLinesEntity and another for OperationCreditEntity data. What you are putting into those tables seems, to me, to overlap quite a bit, and there seems to be a 1;1 relationship. So if you have 100k StatementLinesEntity rows, you likely have 100k OperationCreditEntity rows, duplicating the operationNature data in both. Regardless, where are you stuck? Read/take in your StatementLinesEntity, create OperationCreditEntity instances from it, and call save.

Comment: you mean I should loop over the list and create a instance of OperationCreditEntity then call save method on OperationCreditEntity ?

Comment: is there any way I can set discriminator programmatically, meaning I loop every record I set discriminator to it's own DTYPE. Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: I think you are confused on java inheritance. See my answer, but understand that new OperationChequeEntity() is an instance of OperationCreditEntity. JPA handles writing out the DTYPE for you based on the DiscriminatorValue in subclasses. You should Not ever have to create a 'new OperationCreditEntity()', as it has no meaning to your application - it is why I marked it as abstract in my answer. If you query on the OperationCreditEntity table, there should never be any rows that map to OperationCreditEntity - there is no possible DTYPE entry for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model to me should be more like:

```
@Entity
public class StatementLinesEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long statementLinesId;
  @CreationTimestamp
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date dateOperation;
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "statementLine")
  private OperationCreditEntity operation;
  private BigDecimal amount;
  private String debitAmount;
}

@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
abstract public class OperationCreditEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long operationCreditId;
  @CreatedDate
  private Date operationDate;
  @OneToOne
  private StatementLinesEntity statementLine;
}
```

Any method then that takes in StatementLinesEntity instances can then take in one that references an OperationCreditEntity instance (which can be any one of its subclasses). There is no need to manage, parse or handle String operationNature strings directly, as the operation type will determine the operation nature.

This might change other signatures, serialization (such as JSON though), so if you can't use this and are 'stuck' with your existing StatementLinesEntity data representation YOU need to handle how to create your OperationCreditEntity instances from that data. There is no tool to automatically do it for you. It is as simple as a utility of the form:

```
OperationCreditEntity createOperationInstance(StatementLinesEntity statementLine) {
  String operationNature = statementLine.getOperationNature();
  OperationCreditEntity returnVal = null;
  if "Espece".equals(operationNature) {
    returnVal = new OperationEspecesEntity();
  } else if "Virement".equals(operationNature) {
    returnVal = new OperationVirementEntity();
  } else if "Cheque".equals(operationNature) {
    returnVal = new OperationChequeEntity();
  } else {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
  }
  returnVal.setStatementLine(statementLine);

  return returnVal;
}
```

Just call save using your OperationCreditEntity repository when ever you call this method to get it put into the same transactional context you are making changes to. Also note, those OperationCreditEntity subclasses have data you will need to find a way to fill in on your own; I personally think this data will likely be tied to data available when defining/creating a StatementLinesEntity, so should be generated/created then, not after the fact, but that is up to you.

Added just to be complete:
Yes, you can access the column used to store discriminator values directly in a base entity class. Nothing stops or prevents you from mapping the column as you would any other database column. For Hibernate, it uses "DTYPE", so

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class OperationCreditEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long operationCreditId;
  @CreatedDate
  private Date operationDate;
  @Column(name="DTYPE",insertable=false, updatable=false)
  private String typeValue;
}
```

Notice I marked this as insertable/updatable=false though. It is provider specific if it complains about controlling this value in this way; many try to do so with the hope of changing it. Changing an entity 'type' is not supported. A Caterpillar does not become a Butterfly just by changing a string value. Any caches that hold OperationCreditEntity or some specific subclass type aren't magically going to have the object type changed; JPA requires you to delete the entity and create a new instance (of the proper class) for that data, preferably after flushing the delete operation.

Also note, you can query and use Entity Type Expressions (TYPE) without having a column or other mapping for it.

```
  "Select line from OperationCreditEntity operation join operation.statementLine line where TYPE(operation) IN (OperationEspecesEntity, OperationChequeEntity) and line.somethingElse = :someValue"
```